# How to avoid Repetition of -moz- or -webkit-?

Tags: css

Hello friend i would like to know if there is any way to avoid repetition of Firefox compatibility and chrome in `CSS3`, as we need to enter `-moz- and -webkit-` repetitively  for compatibility. Is it possible to write just once in a page in any way ?

Comment: You can not use it and just apply non-prefixed version of css rule. But it will be less cross-browser

Comment: Sure, use one of any [CSS preprocessors](https://github.com/showcases/css-preprocessors).

Comment: You should consider using some auto prefixer or prefix free libraries.

Comment: @Harry please tell me what is auto prefixer?

Comment: @WaqarAdilMughal: Those are libraries which when included allows you to omit the browser prefixes and use only the standard version. For example, you can see the ones used in CodePen (just click on the Settings gear icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

`-prefix-free lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any CSS code, only when it’s needed.`

[CDN link](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/prefixfree)

[Live DEMO on  dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/)

Comment: +1. I add Lea Verou's Prefix-Free to all of my projects. Reliable, and it does not bloat loading times.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer using [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) respectively the [grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-autoprefixer) or [gulp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-autoprefixer) plugin to generate a css file including prefixes, since I don't like the idea of including an additional library and doing this just in time with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

just found on web

```
js
    // For detecting browser prefix and capabilities
    var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
    var re = /^(Moz|(w|W)ebkit|O|ms)(?=[A-Z])/;
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of how this answers the question